# PROTRACTOR reload()

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, protractor

I new to automation and Protractor, I was able to automate the login page but there is a menu that I need to access to go to a different page where I'm stuck.

There is an `href="#/domains"data-ng-click="reload();"` I tried using xpath and CSS selector with no luck. I really don't know how to automate this menu make it go to the pages I need.

Comment: Could you paste a little more of your test code? I believe you have already tried .click() method of control after finding that item?

Comment: put your code and html  snippet at here, so that we can look into deep

Answer (score 0):

you could try -

```
element(by.css('href*=#/domains')).click();  //css selector *= contains
element(by.css('href^=#/domains')).click(); // css selector ^= start with
element(by.css('href$=ains')).click();     // css selector $= ends with

element(by.css('[data-ng-click="reload()"]')).click(); // this is not the ideal way
```

If nothing of the above works then you would have to go for `nth-child` but for that a little more of your html code!

Comment: var callback = $('[data-ng-click="reload()"]').data( "ng-click")
    var x = eval(callback)
    if (typeof x == 'function') {
        x()
    }

Comment: this is the error I get:         
    From asynchronous test:
    Error
        at Suite.<anonymous> (C:\Users\g801015\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\
protractor\PSM\loginpsm.js:2:4)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\g801015\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\protractor\PSM\loginpsm.js:1:1)
        at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
        at Module.load

Comment: (C:\Users\g801015\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\coffee
-script\lib\coffee-script\register.js:45:36)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
        at C:\Users\g801015\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_mod
ules\jasmine\lib\jasmine.js:71:5
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at Jasmine.loadSpecs

Comment: (C:\Users\g801015\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\
protractor\node_modules\jasmine\lib\jasmine.js:70:18) at Jasmine.execute (C:\Users\g801015\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pr
otractor\node_modules\jasmine\lib\jasmine.js:154:8)
        at C:\Users\g801015\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\frameworks\jasmine.js:118:15 at Function.promise (C:\Users\g801015\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\p
rotractor\node_modules\q\q.js:682:9)

Comment: at C:\Users\g801015\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\frameworks\jasmine.js:90:14 at _fulfilled
(C:\Users\g801015\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protrac
tor\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\g801015\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_
modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\g801015\AppData\Roaming\npm
\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)

Comment: at C:\Users\g801015\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_mod
ules\q\q.js:556:49
at runSingle 
(C:\Users\g801015\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protract
or\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13) at flush (C:\Users\g801015\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\n
ode_modules\q\q.js:125:13) at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9) at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)

Comment: Sorry could not paste it all!

Comment: It's Ok, by looking at your error log . this does not seem to be an issue of element locator! moreover where are you clicking/accessing your element?

Comment: it's a web page that is sort of nav bar on the left side of the page, I was able to make it work half way, it shows the element but does not click on it :S